# File upload using WebDriver JS with typescript

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver

I am new to WebDriver JS with typescript.

I want to upload a file using WebDriver but unable to upload it. I tried the below piece of code but it's not working (Mac user).
Please let me know how can I upload the file.

```
await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator)));           
await driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).sendKeys(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how your page is looking, the answer below is based solely on an assumption.

With this being said, I'm assuming your `locator` is an `input` element with `type="file"`.

Because this elements are harder to be styled using pure CSS there are a lot of web apps (React, Angular or other frameworks) in where the developers often hide this kind of elements and mimic the `input` element with a `div` (or other tag types) that are a bit easier to be styled.

If this is your case, then you first need to make it visible:

```
await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = \"block\"", driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator)));
```

Afterwards you should be able to simply use `sendKeys` to provide the path for your file upload.

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).sendKeys(filePath);
```